# SQL Server VB .NET (or C#) datetime Canonical

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am working with a canonical date in the format `2011-10-24 00:00:00.000`.

There is a SQL Server statement that I can run to get the date in the format in that I need it in.

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(datetime, '2011-10-24 00:00:00.000', 120), 101)` as test
```

Returns

```
10/24/2011.
```

Here is my question.

Is there a way to do this, convert '2011-10-24 00:00:00.000' to 10/24/2011,   in .Net (C# or VB) ?

Comment: If you are looking for a .net solution, I think you would have to work with substrings using `ToShortDateString()` etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB

```
Dim dt As Date = Date.Parse("2011-10-24 00:00:00.000")
Dim newDateString as string = dt.ToShortDateString()
```

In C#

```
System.DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Parse("2011-10-24 00:00:00.000");
string newDateString = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just select it as a date instead of converting to VARCHAR(50) ?

If That's not an option then cast it to a date (DateTime.Parse) and use the properties on the datetime.

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net

```
  Dim newDate As string = CDate(fromdb).ToShortDateString
```

c#

```
  string newDate = DateTime.Parse(fromdb).toShortDateString();
```

pull it from db as a DateTime , let c# / vb.net convert for you

Answer (score 0):

You can parse input string to `DateTime` object with [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) and then format it as you wish with [`DateTime.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method.